# what is this effect called and does C# have it somewhere?

Tags: c#, ajax, popup, fadeout

I am making a web application and I want for when the user clicks a certain button for there to be a "pop up." Not really a pop up, but rather a little window in the browser is created and the rest of the screen is unable to be edited and is darker. Face book has such an effect, but I can't recall where. Also, this http://demo.atmail.org/ has that effect. How the login window is above the regular window and the regular window can not be touched.

What exactly is that effect called(so I can search for it!) and does C# have anything that can do that without hand coding the javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's part of the AJAX Control Toolkit, and it's called the [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) control. Or something like it.

Comment: But that doesn't disable anything else in the page.. though I suppose I could use CSS to make it look more "window"ish..

Comment: What browser are you using? It disables everything on chrome and IE

Comment: gah! it does, it just doesn't change cursors.. ugh. My second dumb question of the day..

Comment: Note you can change the cursor via CSS.

Answer (score 3):

That is called a modal popup. It's an AJAX feature and is not included in any library that comes with Visual Studio. However, the [ASP.Net AJAX control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) can do it and [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) can do it as well (as seen [here](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

A modal popup, typically done in a javascript library such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) (look at the right-hand-side for the various demos)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Modal Popup](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the keyword "lightbox". I believe that's the effect you are looking for.